# Spark Streaming - Checkpoint State EOF Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming job that reads from 2 Delta tables in streams, processes the data, and then writes to a 3rd Delta table. The job is being run with the Databricks service on GCP.

Sometimes the job fails with the following exception. The exception is intermittent and so far I have not been able to come up with the steps to reproduce the issue. What can be the cause for this exception?

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading streaming state file dbfs:/checkpoint_loc/state/0/183/26.snapshot of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0,part=183),dir = dbfs:/checkpoint_loc/state/0/183]: premature EOF reached
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.readSnapshotFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.$anonfun$loadMap$3(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:437)
  at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.$anonfun$loadMap$2(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:437)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:417)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.getLoadedMapForStore(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.getStore(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.get(StateStore.scala:500)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStoreRDD.compute(StateStoreRDD.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:380)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:119)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:813)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1620)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:816)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:672)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[We have tried asking this on Databricks Community Forum](https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001eRne5CAC)

Spark versions - 3.1.2 and 3.2.0
Databricks Runtime - 9.1 LTS and 10.2